# If I finish my work at hand, should I go directly to the manager and ask her to assign new tasks

Tags: communication

I am working in a CRO company. I am wondering whether I should go to the manager to ask for more new tasks if I finish the tasks that my manager previously assigned to me. Since this is a CRO company, we worked for clients and the time we worked will be paid by the clients. So I think if I can work faster, I can save both the client and my company money and also help my company finish more tasks in a given time frame. I am a newbie so I am not sure whether my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 8):

> I am wondering whether I should go to the manager to ask for more new
>   tasks if I finish the tasks that my manager previously assigned to me.

Instead of planning to do that every time your task list runs dry, have a conversation with your manager ahead of time.

Instead of just saying "Give me more tasks" each time, ask something like "What would you like me to do if I finish my assigned tasks?"

That way, you can have a conversation on your approach (you might be told to slow down, not to hurry so much, or to recheck your work more, or to ask for more tasks), and can talk until you and you boss agree on and understand the expectations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, Joe! It helps me think more about the way to communicate with my manager. Instead of asking him to do something to feed my needs, it is definitely better to ask how I can meet his expectations.

Comment: By the way, may I ask how important the working speed is in a workplace? Is this one of the key factors that managers think highly of?

Comment: Thank you, Joe! Gotta you! Actually the fact is that sometimes I found I was working ahead of the time planned and ahead of other teammates. A little unsure whether this is a advantage or disadvantage. Or whether I should slow down and coordinate my speed with most of the other teammates.